# libreoffice sdk 3.4 and SWT Linux issue

Tags: java, swt, libreoffice

I wrote a Java Openoffice addon  (using netbeans)  that launches a SWT window when i click a OOo toolbar button. 
this works fine in windows 7 with libreoffice sdk 3.4 . however for Linux i face a strange problem . when i close the SWT window the whole Libreoffice ( v 3.4) application freezes and becomes unresponsive. i checked the trace log  is reported below (fatal JVM error). this wasn't happening when i was using libreoffice sdk version 3.3 but when i upgraded to libreoffice sdk 3.4 for linux this annoying problem happens and i have no clue what's wrong.

I would be gratefull if someone could propose a clue what's going wrong and how to solve this frustrating problem.

thanks

```
    #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb2703119, pid=18744, tid=3045279440
    #
    # JRE version: 6.0_26-b03
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.1-b02 mixed mode linux-x86 )
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  [libfwili.so+0x17119]  framework::LockHelper::acquireWriteAccess()+0x3d
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
    #

    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread is native thread

    siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x00000001

    Registers:
    EAX=0x08676670, EBX=0xb2716ff4, ECX=0xb78237a0, EDX=0x00000001
    ESP=0xbf9052b0, EBP=0xbf9052c8, ESI=0xbf905318, EDI=0x08949b24
    EIP=0xb2703119, EFLAGS=0x00210296, CR2=0x00000001

    Top of Stack: (sp=0xbf9052b0)
    0xbf9052b0:   08676670 b74c1298 08057268 b27030eb
    0xbf9052c0:   b742859d 944f9ff4 bf9052e8 94353b8b
    0xbf9052d0:   08b1b474 08b1b464 08b24650 b74154ab
    0xbf9052e0:   bf905314 08b1b448 bf905348 943da341
    0xbf9052f0:   bf905318 b741548c b7486ff4 b74155c3
    0xbf905300:   bf905314 08b1b448 b74876c8 b742a313
    0xbf905310:   00000000 08059d08 08b1b478 00000000
    0xbf905320:   08949b50 08949b78 08949b24 b7440368 

    Instructions: (pc=0xb2703119)
    0xb27030f9:   83 fa 03 74 1f 4a 75 2b 8b 40 10 83 ec 0c ff 30
    0xb2703109:   e8 96 6a ff ff eb 19 8b 40 14 83 ec 0c 8b 10 50
    0xb2703119:   ff 12 eb 0c 8b 40 0c 83 ec 0c 8b 10 50 ff 52 08
    0xb2703129:   83 c4 10 8b 5d fc c9 c3 83 6c 24 04 04 eb a4 55 

    Register to memory mapping:

    EAX=0x08676670 is an unknown value
    EBX=0xb2716ff4: <offset 0x2aff4> in /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../basis-link/program/libfwili.so at 0xb26ec000
    ECX=0xb78237a0: <offset 0x537a0> in /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../basis-link/ure-link/lib/libuno_sal.so.3 at 0xb77d0000
    EDX=0x00000001 is an unknown value
    ESP=0xbf9052b0 is an unknown value
    EBP=0xbf9052c8 is an unknown value
    ESI=0xbf905318 is an unknown value
    EDI=0x08949b24 is an unknown value


    Stack: [0xbf8b6000,0xbf906000],  sp=0xbf9052b0,  free space=316k
    Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    C  [libfwili.so+0x17119]  framework::LockHelper::acquireWriteAccess()+0x3d
    C  [libfwkli.so+0x51b8b]  _init+0x42df
    C  [libfwkli.so+0xd8341]  std::set<rtl::OUString, std::less<rtl::OUString>, std::allocator<rtl::OUString> >::insert(rtl::OUString const&)+0x1a09


    ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

    VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

    VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

    Heap
     def new generation   total 4928K, used 3921K [0x96fe0000, 0x97530000, 0x9c530000)
      eden space 4416K,  81% used [0x96fe0000, 0x97365448, 0x97430000)
      from space 512K,  61% used [0x974b0000, 0x974ff0d0, 0x97530000)
      to   space 512K,   0% used [0x97430000, 0x97430000, 0x974b0000)
     tenured generation   total 10944K, used 0K [0x9c530000, 0x9cfe0000, 0xa6fe0000)
       the space 10944K,   0% used [0x9c530000, 0x9c530000, 0x9c530200, 0x9cfe0000)
     compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 2995K [0xa6fe0000, 0xa7be0000, 0xaafe0000)
       the space 12288K,  24% used [0xa6fe0000, 0xa72cce18, 0xa72cd000, 0xa7be0000)
    No shared spaces configured.

    Code Cache  [0xab06f000, 0xab10f000, 0xad06f000)
     total_blobs=234 nmethods=104 adapters=66 free_code_cache=32925056 largest_free_block=0

    Dynamic libraries:
    08048000-0804a000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 661657     /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/unopkg.bin
    0804a000-0804b000 r-xp 00001000 08:06 661657     /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/unopkg.bin
    0804b000-0804c000 rwxp 00002000 08:06 661657     /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/unopkg.bin
    0804c000-08b9b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
    94302000-944ed000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 570825     /usr/lib/libreoffice/basis3.4/program/libfwkli.so
    944ed000-944fa000 r-xp 001eb000 08:06 570825     /usr/lib/libreoffice/basis3.4/program/libfwkli.so
    944fa000-944fc000 rwxp 001f8000 08:06 570825     /usr/lib/libreoffice/basis3.4/program/libfwkli.so
    944fc000-944fd000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
    944fd000-944fe000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    944fe000-94cfe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
    94cfe000-94cff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    94cff000-954ff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
    954ff000-95500000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    95500000-95d00000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
    95d00000-95d2a000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
    95d2a000-95e00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 

  lots of other staff omitted !

    vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.1-b02) for linux-x86 JRE (1.6.0_26-b03), built on May  4 2011 01:23:42 by "java_re" with gcc 3.2.1-7a (J2SE release)

    time: Sun Oct  9 22:06:15 2011
    elapsed time: 7 seconds
```